# Moving postgresql 9.4 data directory in fedora 22

Tags: postgresql, fedora, database-migration

I would like to know how to move the PostgreSQL database directory in a Fedora 22 installation. In Ubuntu, this is very straightforward by using `pg_dropcluster` and `sudo pg_createcluster -d /the/new/location/ 9.4 main`, but Fedora does not appear to have anything of the sort.

I copied the directory `/var/lib/pgsql/data` to a new location and, did the following:

```
su - postgres
service postgresql stop
export PGDATA="/the/new/location/"
echo $PGDATA # gives the correct /the/new/location/
service postgresql start
psql
show data_directory;
```

Which still results in the default `/var/lib/pgsql/data`...

Could someone please either provide a link to a relevant and up-to-date tutorial or explain how to complete the move?

Note: I am aware that this question has been answered for other distributions and older versions of Fedora and Psql, but it seems a lot of the files have been moved about and none of the approaches seem to work for me.

Comment: Edit the parameter data_directory in /the/new/location//postgresql.conf and restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that this method is out of date. The correct way to do it is to add this file with `nano /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service`:

```
.include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/the/new/location/
```

I believe this also requires a reboot.

Afterwards, one still has to set up SELinux correctly before PostgreSQL can start up.